# Where is Influxdb.conf in influxdb2.2(windows)

Tags: influxdb-2

I try to find `Influxdb.conf`, but when I download `Influxdb2.2`, I find there is no file name `Influxdb.conf`, does anyone know how can I find this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration has changed in InfluxDB 2. If you want to change some setting to non-default, you have to create config file in one of the supported formats yourself and make sure `influxd` will use it.

Please see [InfluxDB configuration options](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.2/reference/config-options/) for details.

Comment: It is help me a lot. Thanks!!